# Insert values from one database table to other database table through shell scripting

Tags: database, bash, sqlite, shell, command-line

I am working with 2 databases say **logdb.db** and **logdb2.db** .

I have created a table named **Original** in logdb.db Sqlite database such as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE Original (s_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, s_author TEXT, s_timestamp INT, s_editedby TEXT, s_edited_timestamp INT, s_body_xml TEXT);
```

Similarly, I have created a table named **Edited** and **NonEdited** in logdb2.db Sqlite database such as follows :
    CREATE TABLE Edited (s_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, s_author TEXT, s_timestamp INT, s_editedby TEXT, s_edited_timestamp INT, s_body_xml TEXT);

```
CREATE TABLE NonEdited (s_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, s_author TEXT, s_timestamp INT, s_editedby TEXT, s_edited_timestamp INT, s_body_xml TEXT);
```

Then I attached  logdb2.db to logdb.db as follows from command line:

```
$ sqlite3 logdb.db
$ ATTACH DATABASE '/home/sid/Desktop/Logging/logdb2.db' as DB2;
```

Now, the table Original gets inserted or updated by some other user, so depending on what is being inserted, I want to insert those values into either Edited or NonEdited table. Basically I am targeting the last few rows of the Original table. So I created a shell script file called **test.sh** and The contents are as follows:

```
sqlite3 /home/sid/Desktop/Logging/logdb.db 'insert or replace into DB2.Edited select * from ( select * from Original order by s_id desc limit 10) where s_editedby is NOT NULL order by s_id;'

sqlite3 /home/sid/Desktop/Logging/logdb.db 'insert or ignore into DB2.NonEdited select * from ( select * from Original order by s_id desc limit 10) where s_editedby is NULL order by s_id;'
```

Then I am running the test.sh as follows :

```
watch -n 1 ./test.sh
```

But I am getting the following error when I run the above command saying,

```
Error: no such table: DB2.Edited
Error: no such table: DB2.NonEdited
```

**Where and what am I doing wrong?**

Please note, when all three tables are in same database, I wont get this problem and it works perfectly. I checked the attached database in logdb.db , and it is correct:

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /home/sid/Desktop/Logging/logdb.db                        
2    DB2              /home/sid/Desktop/Logging/logdb2.db                       
sqlite> .tables
DB2.Edited     DB2.NonEdited  Original
```

What could have gone wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

PLEASE NOTE : This is the only way I can do, I cant create triggers. ( I am trying to mock some experiment set up).

Answer (score 0):

ATTACHments are not permanent; you have to do them again when you re-open the database:

```
sqlite3 .../logdb.db 'ATTACH "..."; INSERT ...;'
```

Comment: So this is something I should put in my test.sh script?

Comment: Yes; this is a line from your test.sh script, with an additional ATTACH.

Comment: I tried that. But now it says database locked. As in I am not being able to insert anything into the "Original table"

Comment: "Locked" means that some other connection has an active transaction.